# Akka-streams: how to get flow names in metrics reported by kamon-akka

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-monitoring, kamon

I've been trying to set-up some instrumentation for Akka streams. Got it working, but, even though I named all my Flows that are part of the streams, I still get this sort of names in the metrics: `flow-0-0-unknown-operation`

A simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
val myflow = Flow[String].named("myflow").map(println)

Source.via(myflow).to(Sink.ignore).run()
```

I basically want to see the metrics for the Actor that gets created for "myflow", with a proper name.

Is this even possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current/instrumentations/akka-streams/akka-stream-configuration.html?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Seems meaningless that it's possible to set name but not retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this challenge in my project and I solved by using Kamon + Prometheus. However I had to create an Akka Stream `Flow` which I can set its name `metricName` and export the metric values from it using `val kamonThroughputGauge: Metric.Gauge`.

```
class MonitorProcessingTimerFlow[T](interval: FiniteDuration)(metricName: String = "monitorFlow") extends GraphStage[FlowShape[T, T]] {
  val in = Inlet[T]("MonitorProcessingTimerFlow.in")
  val out = Outlet[T]("MonitorProcessingTimerFlow.out")

  Kamon.init()
  val kamonThroughputGauge: Metric.Gauge = Kamon.gauge("akka-stream-throughput-monitor")
  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new TimerGraphStageLogic(shape) {
    // mutable state
    var open = false
    var count = 0
    var start = System.nanoTime
    setHandler(in, new InHandler {
      override def onPush(): Unit = {
        try {
          push(out, grab(in))
          count += 1
          if (!open) {
            open = true
            scheduleOnce(None, interval)
          }
        } catch {
          case e: Throwable => failStage(e)
        }
      }
    })
    setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
      override def onPull(): Unit = {
        pull(in)
      }
    })

    override protected def onTimer(timerKey: Any): Unit = {
      open = false
      val duration = (System.nanoTime - start) / 1e9d
      val throughput = count / duration
      kamonThroughputGauge.withTag("name", metricName).update(throughput)
      count = 0
      start = System.nanoTime
    }
  }
  override def shape: FlowShape[T, T] = FlowShape[T, T](in, out)
}
```

Then I created a simple stream that uses the `MonitorProcessingTimerFlow` to export the metrics:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("FirstStreamMonitoring")
val source = Source(Stream.from(1)).throttle(1, 1 second)
/** Simulating workload fluctuation: A Flow that expand the event to a random number of multiple events */
val flow = Flow[Int].extrapolate { element =>
  Stream.continually(Random.nextInt(100)).take(Random.nextInt(100)).iterator
}
val monitorFlow = Flow.fromGraph(new MonitorProcessingTimerFlow[Int](5 seconds)("monitorFlow"))
val sink = Sink.foreach[Int](println)

val graph = source
  .via(flow)
  .via(monitorFlow)
  .to(sink)
graph.run()
```

with a proper configuration at `application.conf`:

```
kamon.instrumentation.akka.filters {
  actors.track {
    includes = [ "FirstStreamMonitoring/user/*" ]
  }
}
```

I can see the throughput metrics on prometheus console with the name `name="monitorFlow"`:
[image]